# Accessing values in XML from a variable in Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a XML data as below in a variable p_val:

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
    <env:Header>
        <wsa:MessageID>urn:bda29066-5961-11ec-87ec-0242c5d8b376</wsa:MessageID>
        <wsa:ReplyTo>
            <wsa:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</wsa:Address>
            <wsa:ReferenceParameters>
                <instra:tracking.ecid xmlns:instra="http://xmlns.oracle.com/sca/tracking/1.0">9b657011-42e4-4cf4-a78e-537551de4cc0-0057ca4a</instra:tracking.ecid>
                <instra:tracking.FlowEventId xmlns:instra="http://xmlns.oracle.com/sca/tracking/1.0">27818206</instra:tracking.FlowEventId>
                <instra:tracking.FlowId xmlns:instra="http://xmlns.oracle.com/sca/tracking/1.0">169007626</instra:tracking.FlowId>
                <instra:tracking.CorrelationFlowId xmlns:instra="http://xmlns.oracle.com/sca/tracking/1.0">0000NqYCMWFDGfdLxeG7yW1X_Nsm0003Yk</instra:tracking.CorrelationFlowId>
                <instra:tracking.quiescing.SCAEntityId xmlns:instra="http://xmlns.oracle.com/sca/tracking/1.0">1830036</instra:tracking.quiescing.SCAEntityId>
            </wsa:ReferenceParameters>
        </wsa:ReplyTo>
        <wsa:FaultTo>
            <wsa:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</wsa:Address>
        </wsa:FaultTo>
    </env:Header>
    <env:Body>
        <LaunchSpreadSheetWorkFlowResponse xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/bpmn/bpmnCloudProcess/ISV_ROYALTIES/ISVSpreadSheetMainProcess">
            <instanceNumber xmlns:def="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="def:long"
                xmlns=""
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">79630772</instanceNumber>
        </LaunchSpreadSheetWorkFlowResponse>
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

I want to access the value of the tag: instanceNumber which is 79630772.

If it is a direct payload instead of a variable I tried accessing it using:

```
select *  
FROM XMLTABLE('/Envelope/Body/LaunchSpreadSheetWorkFlowResponse'  
         PASSING   
            xmltype('
                <env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
    <env:Header>
        <wsa:MessageID>urn:bda29066-5961-11ec-87ec-0242c5d8b376</wsa:MessageID>
        <wsa:ReplyTo>
            <wsa:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</wsa:Address>
            <wsa:ReferenceParameters>
                <instra:tracking.ecid xmlns:instra="http://xmlns.oracle.com/sca/tracking/1.0">9b657011-42e4-4cf4-a78e-537551de4cc0-0057ca4a</instra:tracking.ecid>
                <instra:tracking.FlowEventId xmlns:instra="http://xmlns.oracle.com/sca/tracking/1.0">27818206</instra:tracking.FlowEventId>
                <instra:tracking.FlowId xmlns:instra="http://xmlns.oracle.com/sca/tracking/1.0">169007626</instra:tracking.FlowId>
                <instra:tracking.CorrelationFlowId xmlns:instra="http://xmlns.oracle.com/sca/tracking/1.0">0000NqYCMWFDGfdLxeG7yW1X_Nsm0003Yk</instra:tracking.CorrelationFlowId>
                <instra:tracking.quiescing.SCAEntityId xmlns:instra="http://xmlns.oracle.com/sca/tracking/1.0">1830036</instra:tracking.quiescing.SCAEntityId>
            </wsa:ReferenceParameters>
        </wsa:ReplyTo>
        <wsa:FaultTo>
            <wsa:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</wsa:Address>
        </wsa:FaultTo>
    </env:Header>
    <env:Body>
        <LaunchSpreadSheetWorkFlowResponse xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/bpmn/bpmnCloudProcess/ISV_ROYALTIES/ISVSpreadSheetMainProcess">
            <instanceNumber xmlns:def="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="def:long"
                xmlns=""
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">79630772</instanceNumber>
                <name>XYZ</name>
        </LaunchSpreadSheetWorkFlowResponse>
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
            ')
         COLUMNS  
            temp2 varchar2(20)     PATH './instanceNumber'
     ) xmlt  
;
```

The above query returned an empty value.

How should I access the value from a variable?

Comment: What is your actual issue: empty value or how to ass a variable? The latter depends on how that variable and SQL query are related: if they are in the same PL/SQL block, then just pass variable instead of constant XML

Comment: hi, I want to access the value of instanceNumber which is part of XML. and the XML will be present in the variable p_xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify and supply the namespaces:

```
select *  
FROM XMLTABLE(
         XMLNAMESPACES(
            default 'http://xmlns.oracle.com/bpmn/bpmnCloudProcess/ISV_ROYALTIES/ISVSpreadSheetMainProcess',
            'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' AS "env"
         ),
         '/env:Envelope/env:Body/LaunchSpreadSheetWorkFlowResponse'  
         PASSING   
         ...
         COLUMNS  
            temp2 varchar2(20)     PATH '*:instanceNumber'
     ) xmlt  
;
```

The `Envelope` and `Body` come under the SOAP `env` namespace. In the XML document the `LaunchSpreadSheetWorkFlowResponse` node doesn't have a namespace prefix but defines a default namespace, so that default needs to be supplied too. Then it gets slightly awkward for `instanceNumber` as that node redefines (or clears) the default, and defines additional namespaces, but doesn't use them - which puts that node in limbo a bit. I've taken the easy route and wildcarded that with the `*:` prefix.

The less lazy way, I think, is to treat the `LaunchSpreadSheetWorkFlowResponse` as a separate XML fragment with a seconf XMLTable call:

```
select xmlt2.instanceNumber
FROM XMLTABLE(
         XMLNAMESPACES(
            default 'http://xmlns.oracle.com/bpmn/bpmnCloudProcess/ISV_ROYALTIES/ISVSpreadSheetMainProcess',
            'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' AS "env"
         ),
         '/env:Envelope/env:Body/LaunchSpreadSheetWorkFlowResponse'  
         PASSING   
         ...
         COLUMNS  
            LaunchSpreadSheetWorkFlowResponse xmlType     PATH '.'
     ) xmlt1
CROSS JOIN XMLTABLE(
         '.'  
         PASSING   
            xmlt1.LaunchSpreadSheetWorkFlowResponse
         COLUMNS  
            instanceNumber varchar2(20)     PATH 'instanceNumber'
     ) xmlt2
;
```

I'm not sure it's worth it here, and I'd be tempted to stick to the wildcard version.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=731583d8c149da4fcc61d98697f206a1) showing both.

Comment: Thank you it worked. we weren't able to figure out how to reach LaunchSpreadSheetWorkFlowResponse. The default one helped us. Thank you :)